# How to automatically import Gradle build script when opening the project in IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I've imported a gradle project from disk (previously used in eclipse) to IntelliJ.

Every time I launch IntelliJ I get this popup "IntelliJ IDEA found a Gradle build script" even if I click "Import Gradle Project".

Is there a way to permanently link the project with Gradle or at least automate this on launch?

[image: Popup]

Comment: My guess is that you imported it as an Eclipse project, and not as a Gradle project. Delete the project, then reopen it as a Gradle project (by using "Open..." and then selectign the build.gradle file)

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that the issue was connected with OneDrive and its space saving mechanism. Everything went back to normal after disabling below option:
[image: Microsoft OneDrive -> Settings -> Files On-Demand -> disable "Save space and download files as you use them"]

Comment: Useless answer. not everyone uses onedrive. not everyone uses windows. and still everyone can have this problem appear